# Serial Number for iOS 8 Devices - Enterprise App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, enterprise, serial-number

Previously there were several categories or functions that worked to retrieve the serial number programmatically (such as through IOPlatformSerialNumber). Has anyone identified a way to programmatically get the serial number since the release of iOS 8?

I know that apps referencing this information won't be approved on the App Store, and I don't care about any ID's that are unique to the app but can change if the device is reset or apps uninstalled. Has to be the serial number.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm in the same position.

Comment: No I have not; but since iOS 8 has been jailbroken I imagine there are ways to retrieve it on those types of devices; or at least get non-null values returned.